# correlation of two features, which test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, independence, pandas

I have the following table as pandas dataframe with features `feat1` and `feat2`:

```
testframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['feat1', 'feat2'])
testframe['feat1'] = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]
testframe['feat2'] = [1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
```

where the index is the number of observation (e.g people).

I want to find out, if there are **any correlation between feat1 and feat2**. I thought about chi2, but I am not quite sure if it is applicable  in this case.
My real observation has the shape `(43,2)`, so it is quite small I would say.
Are there any tests for correlation (or independency) you can recommend? If so, how would be the implementation in python?
I am happy for every hint on this!
Thanks!

Comment: A chi-squared test in this 2 by 2 table should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for association between the two columns, so you build a contingency table like:

```
tab = pd.crosstab(testframe['feat1'],testframe['feat2'])
tab

feat2   0   1
feat1       
   0    4   0
   1    2   4
```

If there is correlation between you two variables, the counts will populate the diagonal. Like @whuber suggested, you can first try chi-square test:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import fisher_exact, chi2_contingency
chi2_contingency(tab)

(2.100694444444445,
 0.14723225536366139,
 1,
 array([[2.4, 1.6],
        [3.6, 2.4]]))
```

The first value is the chi-square statistic, 2nd is the p-value, degree of freedom and last is the table of expected values. If none of your expected counts is the array is < 5, you can use the chi-square.

In the situation some of the expected has <5, use a fisher test:

```
fisher_exact(tab)
(inf, 0.0761904761904761)
```

The first value is odds ratio (inf because you off diagonal gives 0), and the second is the p-value.

The manual for the test:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html#scipy.stats.chi2_contingency

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisher_exact.html